# HTML hide info bar during page reload

Tags: javascript, html

I need to reload an HTML page every second to monitoring the server status in a automatic control application. I'm able to do this using a Javascript timer, but I have a boring info bar on browser (I'm using Chrome, but I suppose that it is present also in others browser) that inform me that the page is reloading, and it is flashing every second. I would like to remove this info bar. Does someone help me ?

Thanks and regards,
Enrico.

Comment: which bar can you show it?

Comment: If you use ajax instead you can query the server without the page reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this! This is a common case for AJAX - instead of refreshing the page. You'll be able to load data from the Server without reloading anything - on the fly!

Take a closer look at **jQuery's ajax:**

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

---

**BUT**: For monitoring purposes you should take a look at Node.js! This gives you the ability to handle requests and sockets in realtime. Ajax is useful for e. g. preventing page-refreshes but in your scenario i really recommend to use Node.js - its worth it!

**To answer your Question:**

Its not possible to access and control browser-related elements like the yellow info-tooltip  on the bottom left when refreshing the page or hovering a link like it's also not possible to change the cursor's position.